Apply for Schengen visa using brokerage statements
Citizenship: Algeria.
Visa: Tourism.
I want to apply for a tourist visa but it isn't clear for my case. I'm a trader/investor in stock markets. I am using a regulated broker online. In my country this activity is not recognized yet and not banned, so I don't pay tax on my income. Therefore I'm not eligible for local health insurance. But I have good income monthly in hard currencies EURO, USD. The broker offer reports as account confirmation and statements. I can simply withdraw any amount to my debit card.
The issue is: can I apply using online documents? Are invesments brokerage statements acceptable to apply for a France visa? If yes, when filling "current occupation" should I mention the address of my home or the broker? Has anyone applied using brokerage statements?

How long is your proposed trip? The general requirement for financial means to obtain a visa for France is to have at least €65 per day. Not a huge amount, much simpler to withdraw the cash and present ordinary bank account statements. Do you mean you don’t pay tax because your income is below the minimum threshold at which tax becomes due?

@Traveller I suspect that no tax is due because there is no capital gains tax.

I think you should thing yourself like "rich person/retired" and not as "worker". So you should proof you have enough capital. OTOH you need an insurance valid for EU (which you can pay privately). Or you should have your own company and have a regularly paycheck, which may simplify a lot of travels (but that would make you to pay taxes, so you need an accountant to figure out benefit and disadvantages).

I have enough money andI  earn good generated benefits. so independent Financly,  and I can afford trips. I'm not eligible to pay taxes, as the country itself doesn't recognize the activity

Yes. You can put "Derivatives Trader" or "Trader" as your job description. However, depending on the country, this does not signify legitimate employment (since you'll be lacking health insurance, tax papers, etc...).
If you are applying through France, this will unlikely to be even accepted (in TLS). You'll be told that you are missing documents. Other countries (ie: Netherlands/Sweden) might accept and evaluate these documents.

IME you can sign a paper saying that you're aware that you're applying with missing documents and they'll allow you to apply. OP might separately have issues potentially due to limited ties to country anyways.
